# How to Export Data from a Custom Object by using custom vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning

I have written a code to export records from a particular page by using javascript.

```
<button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-button--small" onclick="exportTrademarkTable('Export.csv')">Export</button>
<script>
function downloadCSV(csv, filename) {
    var csvFile;
    var downloadLink;

    // CSV file
    csvFile = new Blob([csv], {type: "text/csv"});

    // Download link
    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

    // File name
    downloadLink.download = filename;

    // Create a link to the file
    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);

    // Hide download link
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";

    // Add the link to DOM
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    // Click download link
    downloadLink.click();
    }
function exportTrademarkTable(filename) {
    var csv = [];
    var rows = document.querySelectorAll("#trademark-table tr");

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td, th");

        for (var j = 1; j < cols.length; j++) 
            row.push(cols[j].innerText);

        csv.push(row.join(","));        
    }

    // Download CSV file
    downloadCSV(csv.join("\n"), filename);

}
</script>
```

As of now I am getting only single(Table) page data. I am trying to export all records which are present in the object

Comment: Saying *please can anyone help me* is not a real question. Please be ask how to achieve something specific.

Answer (score -1):

That is not possible,because the data are coming from server side.you can do it by using jquery